# Error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pic/normal.mode

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Accidentally while working on ubuntu 14.04 fired a command sudo rm -rf * and suddenly everything stopped working.

When I restarted then grub rescue started coming with above error in black screen while starting laptop..!!

Any clue wha happened and can be done ...?

Comment: nothing can be done here. Anyway in which directory you ran this command

Comment: @arpit what do you mean Arpit ...? Is everything lost ...? :(

Comment: if you ran this in `/` then you are done. If not then there might be a solution

Comment: I was in Hadoop user but in root directory

Comment: Yes I did in / directory ...!!

Comment: i don't think you can find a solution now.

Comment: So now Arpit ...? Everything thing needs to install from scratch now ...? Lost everything...?

Comment: yep you have to install everything from scratch